# Python regex for matching Twitter usernames in the beginning of a tweet

Tags: python, regex

I have a tweet text like this:

```
"@user1 @user2 blablabla @user3"
```

I want to use a regex to filter the users in the beginning of a tweet. That would mean @user1 and @user2. There are not always the same number of users, there might be one, two, three...

I'm trying this with re.IGNORECASE:

```
re.compile(ur'^(@[a-z0-9_]*\s)*')
```

But doesn't match what I want, I've tried everything I've come up with, but failed. I'm not very familiar with Python regex, but this how I would do it with egrep:

```
echo "@user1 @user2 blablabla @user3" | egrep '^(@[[:alnum:]_]*[ ]*)*'
```

Thanks

**Editing**

The regex was right, I was just checking the solution the wrong way.

```
tweet = "@user1 @user2 blablabla @user3"
re.compile(ur'^(@[a-z0-9_]*\s)*').match(tweet).groups()
```

Instead of:

```
re.compile(ur'^(@[a-z0-9_]*\s)*').match(tweet).group(0)
```

Clearer version of the regex:

```
re.compile(ur'^(@\w+\s)+').match(tweet).group(0)
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what should be matched that isn't, or what shouldn't be matched that is?

Comment: In the tweet text I mentioned I want ``@user1`` ``@user2`` to be matched and ``@user3`` to not be matched. I mentioned it above.

Comment: Now you've explained what you'd _like_ to happen. What actually _happens_ with the solution you've tried so far?

Comment: I just found the regex is right, but my problem is that I was checking results using `groups()` function, instead of `group(0)`. Sorry I didn't explain myself right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regular expression: `^(@\w+\s)+`.

In `@user1 @user2 blablabla @user3` it will match:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Without `re`, but with `itertools`:

```
>>> tw = "@user1 @user2 blablabla @user3"
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x.startswith('@'), tw.split()))
['@user1', '@user2']
```

Comment: If the tweet is for example `@user1, blablabla` which is a valid tweet, you would get `['@user1,']`

Answer (score 1):

Your egrep version applies a `*` to the space between words but your Python version doesn't. Also, `\s` matches all whitespace, not just spaces; and `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (i.e. `[a-z0-9_]` with `re.IGNORECASE`, since that flag doesn't really affect anything else) is more easily spelled `\w`.

Comment: I see what you mean, but the above Python regex, doesn't work, even if I translate it into: ``ur'^(@\w\s*)*'``

Comment: Sorry, the regex was right, I was just checking results wrong. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: That should be `\w*`; and the `(...)` are also causing a problem for you because the `groups` of the regex will only show the last match. Try using non-capturing parentheses, i.e. `(?:...)`.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean. I didn't know anything about the non-capturing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

If regex isn't necessary:

```
>>> tweet = "@user1 @user2 blablabla @user3"
>>> s = tweet.split()
>>> s[:next(pos for pos, i in enumerate(s) if not i.startswith("@"))]
['@user1', '@user2']
```

Or simplier and more traditional one using a loop:

```
>>> tweet = "@user1 @user2 blablabla @user3"
>>> users = []
>>> for i in tweet.split():
...     if i.startswith("@"):
...         users.append(i)
...     else:
...         break
... 
>>> users
['@user1', '@user2']
```

Comment: I came up with pretty much the same solution you mentioned in your first example, but I feel the urge of finding the right regex, it just got personal, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (if you want to remove them:

```
>>> t = "@user1 @user2 blablabla @user3"
>>> re.compile("^(?:@\w+\s+)*(.*)$").match(t).group(1)
'blablabla @user3'
>>>
```

or this (if you want to only get the users):

```
>>> re.compile("^((?:@\w+\s+)*)$").match(t).group(1).split()
['@user1', '@user2']
>>>
```